# New HTML page after form validation

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show the results of the data gathered by the input. Here's what I've done, but it's not working after I finish filling the fields and after the function returns `true`.

```
    <form name ="reg" action ="" onsubmit ="return checkValidation(this)">//CODE...
```

Here's the called function:

```
function checkValidation()
    {
    var valid = isValidName();
        if(valid)
        valid = isValidEmail();
        if(valid)
        valid = isValidPass();
        if(valid)
        valid = isValidRadio();
        if(valid)
        {
        document.write(document.reg.name.value);
        }
        return valid;
    }
```

Whats the problem? how can I open a new page with this data?
Thank you!

Comment: Maybe forgetting to submit? :)

Comment: @Panagiotis I submitted the form, obviously I don't except the new html to be executed if I haven't done anything

Comment: @Panagiotis he is calling onsubmit,@idish you need to return false it if it is true it will refresh the page and nothing will be printed

Comment: are you redirecting or merely flashing the returned value?

Comment: @AmritpalSingh Do you mind giving a code sample please? Where do I have to write the return false;

Comment: @HeatherWalters I'm not using the returned value in any way I guess, can you tell me please what do I have to do?

Comment: True @amritpal-singh, I thought idish said that he wanted to see the data on a new page. My bad.

Comment: idish use it under document(...) and before the closure of the curly brace.

Comment: Do you want to go to a completely different html page with the data from this form?  Because written this way, your page will refresh if valid returns as true, as amritpal-singh says.

Comment: @Panagiotis Yes!! it works, can you just tell me please why do I had to add the return false;? Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this on your called function:

```
function checkValidation()
{
var valid = isValidName();
    if(valid)
    valid = isValidEmail();
    if(valid)
    valid = isValidPass();
    if(valid)
    valid = isValidRadio();
    if(valid)
    {
    document.write(document.reg.name.value);
    return false;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

what you are actually doing with the **return false;** is cancelling the submit event, because the onSubmit() event requires to return true in order to continue with the actual submit to the page defined in action="" (in your case none, which results in a white page).

Also take in consideration that you have already processed the frontend variables (or show them) by the time that you return false (these procedures happen in your browser). If you want the actual data to be sent to a server (and be on the same page without reload), you should probably use an ajax call to your server side script.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping, by the way, this code doesn't works if I make another document.write(...) before the return false; It would be nice if you could explain me why's that, anyhow I'm accepting your answer, thanks again!

Comment: Are you sure? put a document.write("\n"+document.reg.name.value); to see if it's working properly, before the return false.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkValidation()
{
var valid = isValidName();
    if(valid)
    valid = isValidEmail();
    if(valid)
    valid = isValidPass();
    if(valid)
    valid = isValidRadio();
    if(valid)
    {
    document.write(document.reg.name.value);
    }
    // here if valid is true then page will reload itself and
   //  document.write(document.reg.name.value); will not show any result

    return valid;
}
```

Comment: I now understand the problem, where should I put this code then?